# CPU, Motherboard, HDD, Fan temperature etc. monitor through Nagios of any hardware

Tags: nagios

I am using NagiosXI and I want to monitor HDD, CPU temperature, Fan Speed, etc. of other hosts

Can any one tell what are the way to monitor through NagiosXI.

I am using SNMP method. But haven't got any success.

i have checked with plugin called check_ipmi_sensor but no success.

Comment: what OS will you be checking linux, windows or both etc.

Comment: Does IPMI work on the box, and are you able to pull the sensor readings by hand?

Comment: @tonyroth: both but most mostly for linux server

Answer (score 1):

A detailed answer to that is beyond the scope of an SF answer, but it seems reasonable to me to give you some pointers.  The solution comes in two parts:

1. What plugin to run on the remote machine, and
2. How to run it on the remote machine.

2) is easy: it's [NRPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NRPE#NRPE), or possibly remote execution via ssh (`check_by_ssh`), or perhaps SNMP (though I don't favour that).

1) is the hard bit, and it's not worth doing (2) until you've cracked (1).  This involves finding a way to monitor these parameters on the remote machine, and sensors are a notoriously tricky, BIOS-dependent, standards-unaware, documentation-poor area of work.

So first find a simple command that runs on each machine that gives access to the hardware parameters you want to measure; this is likely to require a different tool on each different hardware platform.  Then wrap it in NAGIOS plugin logic.  Then call it via NRPE.

**Edit**: there are any number of NRPE HOWTOs out there; [this one](http://blog.roozbehk.com/post/25059446631/nrpe-monitoring-linux-remote-hosts-nagios) looks pretty good to me.  But I'll repeat my warning, there's no real point getting the NRPE bit in place until you have the commands to interrogate your hardware ready-to-run, and wrapped in a NAGIOS-friendly wrapper.

Comment: It would be great if you can guide on NRPE(How to). ? Currently i am testing. i have added couple of host and services FYI.

Comment: As I tend to annoyingly repeat from time to time: Nagios plugins are best tested from a "su - -s /bin/bash nagios" ... before adding them to nrpe which will obscure important hints on why something failed.

Comment: Very sound advice!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going the IPMI route: In the end, most plugins will call "ipmitool sdr" and parse the output. Make sure the user nrpe runs the plugin as has the appropriate permissions to do that. Make sure the ipmi_si and ipmi_devintf modules are loaded. Do not forget that not all hardware supports IPMI.

If using any old, hardware-specific, lm_sensors style drivers, thoroughly check whether system stability could be affected, some of these can mess with low level things in surprising manners...

Answer (score 0):

You can pull a bunch of information from the utilities that some of the server sellers provide.  I once monitored server room temperature from the Dell OpenManage utility that had the ambient temperature as seen by the CPU.

It is worth the time and effort to go the NCSA route or other passive test.  The passive route means that, if your system ever builds up past what the active collection server can provide...than the passive tests can be collected and sent to a master server.  Further, if your Nagios server is compromised...the intruder can run programs on any server "connected to" the Nagios server.  With the passive route (and encryption on the NCSA traffic), you can "send" test results to the Nagios server...and if the Nagios server is compromised...well, the intruder still does not have access to the Nagios box.  Further, with passive (NCSA) you can put in ACLs in your switches that only allows traffic to originate from the TESTED server to the Nagios server while blocking traffic from the Nagios server to the TESTED box (hope that makes sense).